# AngularJS Jasmine Testing

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

```html
'use strict';

describe('Hello World example', function() {
 
  it('says hello world!', function () {
    expect("test").toEqual("Hello world!");
  });

});
```

TypeError: undefined is not a function

Why?

Comment: Someone said to make sure angular and angular-mocks are the same versions. I did that. 1.3.14

Comment: You should post more details about how you are trying to run this using Karma. e.g. your Karma config file, etc. We are not mind readers.

Comment: Are you sure you've got the jasmine module defined. We need to know how you're running this.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set this in karma.conf.js

frameworks: ['jasmine']